# How to adjust padding with cutoff or overlapping labels

Tags: python, matplotlib

### Updated MRE with subplots

- I'm not sure of the usefulness of the original question and MRE. The margin padding seems to be properly adjusted for large x and y labels.
- The issue is reproducible with subplots.
- Using `matplotlib 3.4.2`

```py
fig, axes = plt.subplots(ncols=2, nrows=2, figsize=(8, 6))
axes = axes.flatten()

for ax in axes:
    ax.set_ylabel(r'$\ln\left(\frac{x_a-x_b}{x_a-x_c}\right)$')
    ax.set_xlabel(r'$\ln\left(\frac{x_a-x_d}{x_a-x_e}\right)$')

plt.show()
```

[image]

### Original

I am plotting a dataset using `matplotlib` where I have an xlabel that is quite "tall" (it's a formula rendered in TeX that contains a fraction and is therefore has the height equivalent of a couple of lines of text).

In any case, the bottom of the formula is always cut off when I draw the figures.  Changing figure size doesn't seem to help this, and I haven't been able to figure out how to shift the x-axis "up" to make room for the xlabel.  Something like that would be a reasonable temporary solution, but what would be nice would be to have a way to make matplotlib recognize automatically that the label is cut off and resize accordingly.

Here's an example of what I mean:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.figure()
plt.ylabel(r'$\ln\left(\frac{x_a-x_b}{x_a-x_c}\right)$')
plt.xlabel(r'$\ln\left(\frac{x_a-x_d}{x_a-x_e}\right)$', fontsize=50)
plt.title('Example with matplotlib 3.4.2\nMRE no longer an issue')
plt.show()
```

[image]

The entire ylabel is visible, however, the xlabel is cut off at the bottom.

In the case this is a machine-specific problem, I am running this on OSX 10.6.8 with matplotlib 1.0.0

Answer (score 676, accepted):

Use:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.gcf().subplots_adjust(bottom=0.15)

# alternate option without .gcf
plt.subplots_adjust(bottom=0.15)
```

to make room for the label, where [`plt.gcf()`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.gcf.html) means **get the current figure**. [`plt.gca()`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.gca.html), which gets the current `Axes`, can also be used.

Edit:

Since I gave the answer, `matplotlib` has added the **[`plt.tight_layout()`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.tight_layout.html#matplotlib.pyplot.tight_layout)** function.

[See matplotlib Tutorials: Tight Layout Guide](https://matplotlib.org/stable/tutorials/intermediate/tight_layout_guide.html)

So I suggest using it:

```
fig, axes = plt.subplots(ncols=2, nrows=2, figsize=(8, 6))
axes = axes.flatten()

for ax in axes:
    ax.set_ylabel(r'$\ln\left(\frac{x_a-x_b}{x_a-x_c}\right)$')
    ax.set_xlabel(r'$\ln\left(\frac{x_a-x_d}{x_a-x_e}\right)$')

plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: This can be consolidated: `fig, axes = plt.subplots(ncols=2, nrows=2, figsize=(8, 6), tight_layout=True)` instead of adding `plt.tight_layout()` later.

Answer (score 339):

In case you want to store it to a file, you solve it using `bbox_inches="tight"` argument:

```
plt.savefig('myfile.png', bbox_inches="tight")
```

Answer (score 204):

An easy option is to configure matplotlib to automatically adjust the plot size. It works perfectly for me and I'm not sure why it's not activated by default.

**Method 1**

Set this in your matplotlibrc file

```
figure.autolayout : True
```

See here for more information on customizing the matplotlibrc file: http://matplotlib.org/users/customizing.html

**Method 2**

Update the rcParams during runtime like this

```
from matplotlib import rcParams
rcParams.update({'figure.autolayout': True})
```

The advantage of using this approach is that your code will produce the same graphs on differently-configured machines.

Answer (score 10):

`plt.autoscale()` worked for me.

Answer (score 7):

You can also set custom padding as defaults in your `$HOME/.matplotlib/matplotlib_rc` as follows.  In the example below I have modified both the bottom and left out-of-the-box padding:

```
# The figure subplot parameters.  All dimensions are a fraction of the
# figure width or height
figure.subplot.left  : 0.1 #left side of the subplots of the figure
#figure.subplot.right : 0.9 
figure.subplot.bottom : 0.15
...
```

Answer (score 7):

There is also a way to do this using the OOP interface, applying `tight_layout` directly to a figure:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
fig.set_tight_layout(True)
```

https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/figure_api.html

Answer (score 1):

The more modern suggestion would be to use `layout='constrained'`.  It won't be much different in this case, but is more flexible than `layout='tight'`.

```
fig, axes = plt.subplots(ncols=2, nrows=2, figsize=(8, 6),
                         layout='constrained')
axes = axes.flatten()

for ax in axes:
    ax.set_ylabel(r'$\ln\left(\frac{x_a-x_b}{x_a-x_c}\right)$')
    ax.set_xlabel(r'$\ln\left(\frac{x_a-x_d}{x_a-x_e}\right)$')

plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

for some reason sharex was set to True so I turned it back to False and it worked fine.

```
df.plot(........,sharex=False)
```

Answer (score -4):

You need to use sizzors to modify the axis-range:

```py
import sizzors as sizzors_module

sizzors_module.reshape_the_axis(plt).save("literlymylief.tiff")
```

Comment: What on earth is sizzors?