# Plotting random numbers from a given distribution along with their expected value in Python

Tags: python, matplotlib

I want to  compare randomly generated values sampled from certain distributions to the actual functions of those distributions.

I'm currently using `matplotlib` for plotting and `numpy` for sampling.

I found a working example for what I'm trying to achieve

```
# read mu, sigma, n
x = np.random.normal(mu, sigma, n)
count, bins, ignored = plt.hist(x, bins="auto", density=True)
plt.plot(bins, 1 / (sigma * np.sqrt(2 * np.pi)) * np.exp(-(bins - mu) ** 2 / (2 * sigma ** 2)), linewidth=2, color='r')
plt.show()
```

So `x` is the sample array, and they plot it using histograms, and they use the actual pdf for the function.

How would that work for the binomial distribution for instance?
I followed a similar pattern:

```
x = np.random.binomial(N, P, n)
count, bins, ignored = plt.hist(x, bins="auto", density=True)
plt.plot(bins, scipy.special.comb(N, bins) * (P ** bins) * ((1 - P) ** (N - bins)), linewidth=2, color='r')
plt.show()
```

However the graph I'm getting doesn't really look right:

[image: graph]

Well the pdf's height doesn't seem to match the histograms. What am I doing wrong? Is it the binomial function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you got it right.  Your formula for the pdf looks correct.  Try it with a much larger number of samples (n) from your binomial.  Recall the area under the pdf integrates to 1.0.  By using the `density=True` your histogram is normalized as well, which is good.  What happens when you don't have a large enough `n`?  You have empty bins...and the others are relatively higher.

I ran your code for N=1000, P=0.7, n=10,000 and got a decent plot.  E[X] = 700 for this.  Plot looks reasonable enough...

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The bins = "auto" defaults to the method `sturges`, which only accounts for data size. It is only good for gaussian data and underestimates the number of bins for large non-gaussian datasets.

Answer (score 0):

I wasn't totally sure why you were trying to estimate the PDF based on the return parameters from the `hist` function, but it's possible to plot this just using scipy's `binom.pmf` (probability mass function, the discrete equivalent of the PDF):

```
N, P = 100, 0.5
f, ax1 = plt.subplots(figsize=(10, 5))
x = np.random.binomial(N, P, 50000)
count, bins, ignored = ax1.hist(x, bins="auto")
ax2 = ax1.twinx()
ax2.plot(range(100), binom.pmf(range(100), n=N, p=P))
ax2.grid(None)
plt.show()
```

Output:

[image]

(I hid the grid in the second `ax` because the two y-axes aren't quite aligned, based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29099515).)