# Matplotlib ylabels not aligned vertically (two y axes)

Tags: python, matplotlib, axis-labels

I have a problem to align y axes labels when I add a second y axis.
When I use command like bellow location of labels are not the same.

```
ax.set_ylabel('gram', fontsize='xx-small', rotation=0, loc="top")
ax2.set_ylabel('kg', fontsize='xx-small', rotation=0, loc="top")
```

How to fix it?
[output when I use loc='top' on both axes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D31Yc.png)

I tried to use (alternatively to **loc**) **va** and **ha** text parameters, but this is not work correctly.

Comment: What do you want your plot to look like? Where do you want to place the labels?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I align gridlines for two y-axis scales using Matplotlib?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26752464/how-do-i-align-gridlines-for-two-y-axis-scales-using-matplotlib)

Answer (score 2):

The vertical alignments are different in your example:  Make them the same:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
fig,axs = plt.subplots(1, 2, constrained_layout=True, figsize=(5, 3))
ax = axs[0]
ax2 = ax.twinx()
ax.set_ylabel('gram', rotation=0, loc="top")
ax2.set_ylabel('kg', rotation=0, loc="top")
ax = axs[1]
ax2 = ax.twinx()
ax.set_ylabel('gram', rotation=0, loc="top", va='bottom')
ax2.set_ylabel('kg', rotation=0, loc="top", va='bottom')
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: thank you. 
it works, however I don't understand why va='bottom' effectively align to the top :)

Comment: `va` is the vertical alignment relative to the position of the label.  So the label is put at `y=1.0` (in axes-relative co-ordinates) , and the text is then aligned with that: https://matplotlib.org/stable/tutorials/text/text_props.html