# Plt.show shows full graph but savefig is cropping the image

Tags: python, matplotlib

My code is succesfully saving images to file, but it is cropping important details from the right hand side. [Answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6774086/why-is-my-xlabel-cut-off-in-my-matplotlib-plot) exist for fixing this problem when it arises for `plt.show`, but it is the `savefig` command that is incorrectly producing the graph in this example. How can this be fixed?

The relevant sample of my code:

```
import glob
import os
for file in glob.glob("*.oax"):
    try:
        spc_file = open(file, 'r').read()
        newName = file[6:8] + '-' + file[4:6] + '-' + file[0:4] + ' ' + file[8:12] +  ' UTC (Observed) - No Sea Breeze Day'
        plt.title(newName, fontsize=12, loc='left')
        plt.savefig('X:/' + newName + '.png')        
        plt.show()
    except Exception:
        pass
```

And the images (top is `plt.show` and bottom is file produced from `savefig`:

[image: Image when shown with plt.show]
[image: Image when saved to file]

---

Comment: Can you make a simple example that others can test, preferably without having to download extra data and packages?

Comment: @Neapolitan. That's a bit beyond my skill set. The answer provided below suggests that there is a generic solution for this problem, independent of the data.

Comment: @Neopolitan I don't know how the problem has arisen, so I'm not sure how to produce simpler data that could replicate it.

Answer (score 326, accepted):

You may try

```
plt.savefig('X:/' + newName + '.png', bbox_inches='tight')
```

Or you may define figure size like

```
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(9, 11))
...
plt.savefig(filename, bbox_inches = 'tight')
```

Comment: This has to be the default option, bbox_inches='tight'. I used it in conjunction with a high dpi value and it worked wonderfully well.

Comment: Using plt.gcf().set_size_inches(width,height) and then plt.savefig(filename, bbox_inches = 'tight') works even better for nerdy-detailed-obsessive-compulsive-disorder customization

Comment: For future searchers using `mlflow.log_figure`, this answer helped solve the issue of my legend being clipped/cropped. The full solution is: `mlflow.log_figure(..., save_kwargs={'bbox_inches': 'tight'})`

Answer (score 11):

As described in the [documentation](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.tight_layout.html) you may also try:

```
plt.tight_layout()
```

Comment: It works for me, but it changes the ratio width/height. Any idea how to also preserve the ratio?

Comment: Yes, you can set the ratios accordingly by using "plt.figure(figsize=(9, 3))" ;)

Comment: I like this better than the accepted answer: it is easier to remember, and can be autocompleted to reduce human error.

Answer (score 0):

Another very easy solution is saving a plot to a *.pdf* format. This have worked for me many times when  `bbox_inches = 'tight'`and `plt.tight_layout()` didn't help.

Syntax is just:

```
plt.savefig('X:/' + newName + '.pdf')
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and none of the answers could help me. Saving the plot as a pdf saved the entire graphic including the axis labeling, but I could not insert the pdf into Word.
In the end it worked for me by saving the plot as SVG. The entire graphic was saved, which I was then able to insert into Word.
Code for saving as svg: `plt.savefig('my_plot.svg', format='svg')`