# How I can save big tables as image with pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, matplotlib

I want to save a table with 1538 rows by 4 columns as an image,
I saw [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35634238/how-to-save-a-pandas-dataframe-table-as-a-png) post and tried this code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
import pandas as pd 
from pandas.tools.plotting import table

df = pd.read_csv('filepath.csv') 
ax = plt.subplot(111, loc='top') 
ax.xaxis.set_visible(False)  
ax.yaxis.set_visible(False)  

table(ax, df) 

plt.savefig('mytable.png')
```

but what I got was [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/88BOW.png), and the goal is a big image "scrollable". Is there anyway to do It?

Comment: your code looks messy. Please update with proper code.

Comment: Check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/37428142/2666859

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realize you mentioned image, but I would look into trying to make it into an html page. Luckily, pandas can handle all of it for us with the [`df.to_html()` method](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_html.html). Definitely take a look at the documentation which allows lots of nifty options (html classes, ids, borders, etc etc).

But as an example, it would look something like this:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(1538, 4),
                columns=['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'])
with open('dataframe.html', 'w') as outfile:
    outfile.write(df.to_html())
```

Then you can just open up `dataframe.html` in any browser.