# Pandas' figure is getting cut when saving

Tags: python, pandas, plot

The DataFrame `data`, where `date` is an index look like:

```
date        count   
2017-03-20  119
2017-03-29  100
2017-04-03  118
2017-04-10  113
```

`date`(index) has a format `datetime64[ns]`.

When i try to plot it with

`p = data.plot(kind="bar")`,

it adds hours:minuts:seconds to the axis values(to dates). So, when i save it with

```
fig = p.get_figure()
fig.savefig('figure.jpeg'),
```

The frame cuts off days,month,yeear and leaves only zeros from minuts,seconds...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`strftime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DatetimeIndex.strftime.html) + [`tight_layout`](https://matplotlib.org/users/tight_layout_guide.html):

```
import matplotlib.ticker as ticker
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

ticklabels = data.index.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
ax = data.plot(kind="bar")
plt.tight_layout()
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(ticker.FixedFormatter(ticklabels))
```

Comment: Please, see the edit

Comment: If change `data.plot(kind="bar",figsize=(12,8))` it dont help?

Comment: That works, but is the plot square in your output too? The histogram itself became really small. Is there a way to increase space for ticks with no harm to hist size?

Comment: Hmmm, hard question for me, but maybe help [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6776578/2901002)

Comment: Ok, thanks for help