# seaborn python not showing y label

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have the code below and this is not showing the "y-label". I have already tried :

```
ax.ylabel = "fisdaopdfidsa"
gca.ylabel = "fdsaifds"
```

Anyone can help?

```
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.ticker as ticker
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.plot(violencia["ano"],violencia["taxa de homicidios"])
plt.title("Homicides Rate ")
plt.xticks(violencia["ano"])
tick_spacing=2
ax.set_ylabel("fsdfsaoi pfdasiopfidsa")
ax.set_xlabel("fsdfsaoi pfdasiopfidsa")
ax.yaxis.label.set_color('red')
ax = plt.gca()
ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(ticker.MultipleLocator(tick_spacing))
```

Comment: you dont use `seaborn`; might be just `plt.ylabel("text")`

Comment: you can try `plt.tight_layout()` at the end of your script

Comment: also see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6774086/why-is-my-xlabel-cut-off-in-my-matplotlib-plot/6776578#6776578 but use `plt.gcf().subplots_adjust(left=0.15...)`