# How to show full sentence of tick label using matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, scipy, dendrogram

I'd like to create a dendrogram with many records and long-sentence label.
The output doesn't show the full sentence of tick label. I tried to adjust font size and plot size, but didn't work.
How can I show the full sentence of tick labels? (widen the tick label space?)

[image]

Comment: Some options are: make a taller figure, reduce the size of the ticklabel font (and use either a *much* higher dpi or save the figure in a vector format file) or reduce the number of ticklabels. Given the number of ticks here it might be the case that it is not practical to do anything other than reduce the number of tick labels - or split the plot into multiple separate plots

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why is my xlabel cut off in my matplotlib plot?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6774086/why-is-my-xlabel-cut-off-in-my-matplotlib-plot)