# Size my matplotlib charts so that size of chart is always consistent even with widely varying ylabel lengths

Tags: python, matplotlib, svg

I've run into an issue with my matplotlib chart outputs, which I am exporting as SVG text (using `fig.savefig()` and rendering as server-side rendered analytics in a web app.

One of these charts is a horizontal bar chart - as pictured below in stunning detail -

```
                  _______________________
       item1_name |----                 |
       item2_name |--------             |
        something |----------           |
thing thing thing |-------------        |
      other thing |---------------------|
                  ---1---2---3---4---5---
                        some metric
```

My problem is when these labels are very large, they are causing trouble.

When using `fig.tight_layout()`:

```
                  _______________________
ry Very Long Name |----                 |
eft Side Gets Cut |--------             |
 Keep Getting Cut |----------           |
names are getting |-------------        |
   cutoff on left |---------------------|
                  ---1---2---3---4---5---
                        some metric
```

*Plot renders as normal but X axis labels are cut off on the left side (oddly the plot actually seems to render* larger *than normal in some cases)*

When using `rcParams.update({'figure.autolayout': True})`:

```
                                 ________
My Very Very Very Very Long Name |-     |
                Now I Am Smushed |--    |
             Chart is very small |---   |
             but names are being |----- |
                rendered in full |------|
                                 -1----5-
                                 some metr
```

*Names render in full, but plot is squished to make space.*

I am hoping to **make it so plot is always the exact same size** regardless of scale of x axis, length of y labels - while also **never cut ylabels on the left**.

Is there an mpl convenience method to render the whole chart & labels without distortion/cutoff? I believe `tight_layout()` is supposed to do this but only works for xlabels.

If not, is there a method to get the size required for the ylabel, which I could then use with `fig.set_size_inches()`, like so:

```
label_inches_needed = get_label_size(axes)
plot_consistent_height = 4
plot_consistent_width = 10
fig.set_size_inches(plot_consistent_width + label_inches_needed, plot_consistent_height)
```

Appreciate any suggestions and thank you for looking at my charts.

Reference -
[Why is my xlabel cut off in my matplotlib plot?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6774086/why-is-my-xlabel-cut-off-in-my-matplotlib-plot)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To make sure labels are not cut out, try using the option bbox when saving. I can't verify for your case since you did not provide code for your figure but this usually does the trick.

```
plt.savefig(figname, bbox_inches = "tight")
```

Comment: Thank you, this produced the desired result