# pandas plot ylabel feature names doesn't fit

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, matplotlib

I use pandas DataFrame to show feature importance plot.

However some features doesn't fit to ylabel due to their long names.

```
data = pd.DataFrame({'feature': feature,'importance': importance}).sort_values(by='importance', ascending=False)[0:10]
ax = data.plot(kind='barh', x='feature', y='importance')
ax.figure.savefig(filename)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution: **bbox_inches**

```
ax.figure.savefig(filename, bbox_inches='tight')
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can adjust the `left` parameter with [matplotlib.pyplot.subplots_adjust](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.subplots_adjust.html):

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

ax = data.plot(kind='barh', x='feature', y='importance')
plt.subplots_adjust(left=0.3)  # call after drawn the plot, but before showing or saving
ax.figure.savefig(filename)
```

Comment: It worked but it crops from right side: https://prnt.sc/vgqg6s Is there any what to without crop?

Comment: Did you try to also change the `right` parameter? Or, the figure size?

Answer (score 0):

Use `plt.tight_layout()` before saving, but after plotting, as follows:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

ax = data.plot(kind='barh', x='feature', y='importance')

plt.tight_layout()

ax.figure.savefig(filename)
```

More details in another thread: https://stackoverflow.com/a/17390833/13240220

Answer (score 0):

Use [`constrained_layout`](https://matplotlib.org/tutorials/intermediate/constrainedlayout_guide.html); it is similar to `tight_layout`, but more flexible:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(constrained_layout=True)
data.plot(kind='barh', x='feature', y='importance', ax=ax)
```