# Axis labels are cut off when using subplot with just one plot

Tags: python, matplotlib, subplot

I have plot with axis labels looking like this

[image: subplot(111)]

created by this code:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig = plt.figure()
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(111)
ax1.set_xlabel('x-label 1')
ax1.set_ylabel('y-label 1')

plt.show()
```

If I resize the master object of the plot (in this case the window) to smaller size, the axes labels are cut off like so

[image: height cut off]

and

[image: width cut off]

but if I create the subplot with two plots (the second one doesn't have to be populated with a plot), the labels are not cut off, even though the plot is smaller:

[image: subplot(211)]

and

[image: subplot(121)]

How do I prevent the labels from being cut off when using `add_subplot(111)` and resizing its master?

Comment: use tight or constrained layout: `plt.figure(layout='constrained')`

Comment: Thank you, that works! Want to put it into an answer?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to adjust padding with cutoff or overlapping labels](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6774086/how-to-adjust-padding-with-cutoff-or-overlapping-labels)

Comment: No, it does not (resizing the master still cuts off the labels with that method).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use a `tight` or `constrained` layout by setting for instance

```
fig = plt.figure(layout='constrained')
```

See [Constrained Layout Guide](https://matplotlib.org/stable/tutorials/intermediate/constrainedlayout_guide.html) for more details.